# Boolean operation in List or Pandas -- bug or misunderstanding?

Tags: python, pandas

The following truth table for the `AND` operation is confusing to me. Is it a bug or am I misunderstanding/missing something?

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'input_1':[True, False, True, False],'input_2':['True','True','False','False'], 'expected_AND':['True','False','False','False']})
x['actual_AND'] = x['input_1'] & x['input_2']
display(x)
```

[image]

Comment: 'True' is a string, not a boolean! That it's your problem! If someone already answered that, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

The `input_2` column contains strings, not booleans. Any non-empty string is truthy, so all those values are equivalent to `True`.

Remove the quotes in `input_2`, just like `input_1`.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'input_1':[True, False, True, False],'input_2':[True,True,False,False], 'expected_AND':['True','False','False','False']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.logical_and` from numpy:

```
x['actual_AND'] = np.logical_and(x['input_1'], x['input_2']); 
display(x)
```

Then, you get:

```
   input_1 input_2 expected_AND actual_AND
0     True    True         True       True
1    False    True        False      False
2     True   False        False      False
3    False   False        False      False
```